# JavaScript: getElementById not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html

I've this very simple JavaScript to display the selected option in the span. It works fine in all the browsers except IE8.

Code -

```
<select onchange="searchdisplay(this.value)">
<option>kill</option>
<option>bill</option>
<option>by</option>
<option>torentino</option>
<option>is </option>
<option>not </option>
<option>good</option>
<Select>

<span id="container">
<span>
```

Script -

```
<script>
function searchdisplay(val)
{
    var div = document.getElementById('container');
    div.innerHTML =  val;
}
</script>
```

Any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: IE8 is so broken, you amy be able to fix it by simply renaming `var div` to something else, ex: `var div2`. Your `getElementById` usage looks correct.

Comment: Do you run the script after DOM ready?

Comment: Is that second `<span>` tag supposed to be `</span>`? @Sergio The function will only run via the `<select>` tag's `onchange` event, so a user would have to react pretty fast to change options on the `<select>` before the `<span>` loaded (assuming the function had already been parsed).

Comment: @ajp15243 :) some people are fast with the mouse... No, I just wondered if IE/script looks for the ID before the whole page is loaded. But you are right, it's just triggered `onchange`

Comment: @techfoobar - i tried renaming it but didnt work.

Comment: Errors in the console? Could you post the entire page?

Comment: @ajp15243 - I closed the span but still didn't work.

Comment: @Sergio Unless an absolutely ridiculous amount of resource loading or code execution is happening between loading the `select` and the `span` to give the user the chance to select a different option (highly unlikely), or `searchdisplay` is called elsewhere before that part of the DOM is loaded, there shouldn't be any issues with when this is run vs. when the DOM is loaded, given the posted code at least.

Comment: @Juhana - thats all my page has except those regular head, body tags.

Comment: Could you still do it, because there's nothing there that would explain the problem. And are there errors in the console? Have you confirmed that JavaScript works on other sites (so it's not disabled in IE)?

Comment: Try closing your `<select>` tag as well (end it with `</select>` instead of `<Select>`).

Comment: @Sagar Raj: I suspect this is a markup issue,validate your HTML at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

Comment: I've made a JSBin example [here](http://jsbin.com/ukiquv/2/edit) (since jsfiddle apparently is super-broken in IE8) and tried it in Chrome on Win7, worked fine. Tried it in IE8 on a WinXP VM and it doesn't work, and I see no console errors. I even corrected the markup to close the `<select>` and `<span>` tags correctly, and even added `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `this.value` in IE8 change it to :-

`<select onchange="searchdisplay(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">` and it shall work fine.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vMkm/)

In your current code

Fix your markup too as others said in the comments.

```
<select onchange="searchdisplay(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option>kill</option>
    <option>bill</option>
    <option>by</option>
    <option>torentino</option>
    <option>is</option>
    <option>not</option>
    <option>good</option>
</select>
<span id="container"></span>
```

Ideal way is to add `value` attribute for the select options. and do `this.value` which probably is guaranteed to work.

Comment: +1 I just confirmed this in IE8 with my JSBin example from my comment, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

your script does work.. it just that your value attribute does not exist,

i guess the other browsers are not looking for the "value" attributes.. and uses the text of the option when it's missing but IE8 does need it..

add the value attribute to each option and it will be ok

```
<select onchange="searchdisplay(this.value)">
<option value="kill">kill</option>
<option value="bill">bill</option>
<option value="by">by</option>
<option value="torentino">torentino</option>
<option value="is ">is </option>
<option value="not ">not </option>
<option value="good">good</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/04/internet-explorer-8-fix-event-handling-or-dont-release-it/) specifically about IE8 event handling says :

> Microsoft’s event handling is filled with shortcomings, where some of
>   the more serious are:
>
> 1. Just one global event object, instead of local objects per event.
> 2. When using the attachEvent method, the keyword this in the event handling
>      function refers to the window object, and not the HTML event it
>      actually occurred on.
> 3. No support for capture phase. Different syntax, with requiring the “on”
>      prefix for the event in question.

Item 2 implies to me that the `this` in your `onchange` will be the `window` not the clicked element. To check this out log, or better in IE8, alert the value passed into `searchDisplay`

The following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getOption(e) {
    var event = e|window.event;
        alert(event.srcElement.innerHTML); // works in IE but shows the select object
        alert(event.target.innerHTML); // works well in FF, shows the right option
}

</script>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<select size="4" oncontextmenu="getOption(event)">
    <option value="1"> option1 </option>
    <option value="2"> option2 </option>
</select>
</body>
```

might help you, it is posted [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?216003-Issue-in-HTML-select-list-event-handling-in-IE-%288%29) to get around a very similar situation with selects.