# 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i am getting the error while tryin to get the id and place the value from the xml..the problem is only with the html...not on the xml part because while using alert we get the xml values..i think the DOM elements is not fully loaded..also help me where to call the function such that all the DOM elements are loaded successfully..

Thanks in advance..

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">

             var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            var a;
            function loadXML(xmlFile) 

            { 

              xmlDoc.async="false"; 

              xmlDoc.onreadystatechange=verify; 

              xmlDoc.load(xmlFile); 

              xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement; 
              a=xmlObj;
              document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=a.childNodes(0).text;
              document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=a.childNodes(1).text;
              document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=a.childNodes(2).text;
              document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=a.childNodes(3).text;    

            }   
            loadXML('note.xml');
            function verify() 

            { 

              if (xmlDoc.readyState != 4) 

              { 

                return false; 

              }  

            }

        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
            <div id="div1">
                <b>To:</b> <span id="to" name="to" >aba</span><br />
                <b>From:</b> <span id="from" name="from">abar</span><br />
                <b>Message:</b> <span id="message" name="message">avfdas</span><br />
                <b>Body:</b> <span id="body" name="body">hgj</span>
            </div>


        </body>
    </html>
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
        <to> Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body1>Don't forget me this weekend!</body1>
    </note>
```

Comment: See here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631990/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking along the right lines but you need to understand that you can try to access the nodes of the xmldocument only when the xml document has completely been loaded.

When the xmldoc is loaded (since it happens asynchronously), whatever function you set to onreadystatechange, will get called. When the readyState is 4, that means the document has loaded and only after that you should try accessing the doc's elements.

Also, your code will only work in IE as that's the only browser that supports ActiveXObjects. For a cross browser solution, do something like the foll: (taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        }
        catch(ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

function handler()
{
    if (oReq.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            console.log(oReq.responseText); // You should try accessing the DOM here.
        }
    }
}
var oReq = getXMLHttpRequest();
if (oReq != null) {
    oReq.open("GET", "http://localhost/test.xml", true);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = handler;
    oReq.send();
}
else {
    window.console.log("AJAX (XMLHTTP) not supported.");
}
```